# External script on CPanel Cronjob with PHP

Tags: php, cron

I am running a cronjob on CPanel, a php script containing:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://otherdomain.abc/script.php");
?>
```

My purpose is to execute a PHP script that MUST be located in a different server (which doesn't allow me to set up cronjobs)

**What happens**:

Script doesn't work, and since it contains no errors, I suppose a cronjob cannot interpet redirections.

So I thought about doing file_get_contents() [Which works fine], to ping the site and force the execution. But, is that the right approach?

Thanks :)

Comment: You cannot use  'header()' in a cronjob, because header() redirects a client. so  file_get_contents() is better here.

Comment: maybe ignore_user_abort() helps too

Comment: `file_get_contents('http://....')` instead, so you're doing an http request to that url, instead of trying to redirect to it. just make sure url_fopen is enabled...

Answer (score 0):

Use www.guardiano.pm ;) Is a free service that can call url in GET or POST as much as you want, have a look at the video

Discalimer: is my pet project